# Should I use "onclick" or "ontextchanged" event for my textboxes to hide a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, textchanged

I am using asp.net c# and what I would like to achieve is when the user clicks within a text box on the form to hide a label (I am using this label for some feedback).

I was trying something like the following code but the label is never hided:

```
hiddenMsg.Visible = true;
.
.
.

private void compTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            hiddenMsg.Visible = false;
        }
}
```

In my aspx file I have the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="compTxt" runat="server" TabIndex='11' AutoPostBack="true" ontextchanged="compTxt_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
```

[Updated my question]

I am using Javascript to achieve my goal and also I am using style.display attribute in JS instead of Visible = false in order to achieve that, however I am not sure about the method I am using in asp:TextBox, Could anyone help me about how call a JavaScript method from a asp:TextBox ?

```
function hideMsgs() {
      document.getElementById('<%= hiddenMsg.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
}  

<asp:Label ID="hiddenMsg" runat="server" Text="Successfully Saved" style="display:inherit;"/>


<asp:TextBox ID="compTxt" runat="server" TabIndex='11' OnClientClick="hideMsgs()"/>
```

Comment: Do you really need to post-back the page to hide a label? You can do it in the client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the IsPostBack check, it will always be a postback.

```
private void compTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hiddenMsg.Visible = false;
}
```

For a client side solution, in your page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    compTxt.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('hiddenMsg').style.display = 'none';");
}
```

If you are using a Master Page in your project use this line instead in your page load:

```
compTxt.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + hiddenMsg.ClientID + "').style.display = 'none';");
```

Comment: AS SmartPC said, this is not a good way to accomplish this, you want to use javascript so it is done client-side without a postback.  Postbacks really slow things down and something like this you want crisp.

Comment: Chrome, yes I changed my code behind look like above, are you sure that you can add "onclick" event on an <asp:TextBox> ?

Answer (score 0):

A click on the clientside never leads to a postback. You need a postback to handle that code. I would suggest to use javascript to handle your click event so that you can hide your label clientside. Then no postback is needed.

Comment: @SmartPCInformate ¿Seguro? I mean, no click in the client-side leads to a postback in ASP.NET Web Forms? ...

Comment: Yes, a click in a textbox on clientside does not lead to a postback by default. And otherwise postbacks only occur when you specify autopostback=true or some other mechanism.